# When should I use 'its' vs 'their'?

Tags: grammaticality

I have a sentence as follows:

> Architectural analysis is an initial step in defining the system components and **their** relationships.

Can I use "**its** relationships" instead of "**their** relationships"?

Answer (score 3):

SHORT ANSWER:
If you say ***its*** relationships it will not mean the same thing as *their relationships*, and it will take some rewriting to make it grammatical.

LONG ANSWER:
*Their relationships* means the relationships **among** the system components; *their* must refer to components, because that is the only plural Noun Phrase in this clause.

*Its relationships* would have no very clear referent: there is no singular Noun Phrase in this clause to which it can refer. Keep in mind that pronouns do not take mere nouns as their referents, but entire Noun Phrases. It is true that a noun **can** act as a Noun Phrase, all by itself. But that is not the case with *system* here: *system* is an attributive noun modifying *components*.

If you want your *its* to refer to the system, you will have to rewrite; and that's not straightforward.  You may, for instance, write:

> ... defining the components of the system and its relationships.

But that is ambiguous; many readers will take that to mean *the components of the system* AND *the components of its relationships*, which is not the same thing as *the components of the system* AND *the relationships of the system*.

So instead you might write:

> ... defining the system**'s** components and its relationships.

Now *it* refers to *system*. Moreover, they are parallel: both are in the possessive case, so you may rewrite this more simply without *its*:

> ... defining the system's components and relationships.

This seems to be what you are aiming at.

Note however that this means something different. The relationships you are defining are  no longer the system's internal relationships, the relationships between its various components, but the system's **external** relationships with other entities which are not named.

Answer (score 2):

The "relationships" belong to the "components," which are plural. Thus, you use "their," because it is plural.